# Von Dyck's Theorem about free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

In Hungerford's "Algebra", he states Von Dyck's theorem as follows: Let X be a set and Y a set of reduced words on X, and G the group defined by generators $x\in X$ and relations $w=e, w\in Y$. If $H=\langle X\rangle$ and H satisfies all the relations in Y, then there exists and epimorphism $G\rightarrow H$.

But I have trouble with $H=\langle X\rangle$. If $G=\langle X\rangle$ and $H=\langle X\rangle$, then isn't it the same group? What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the difference that $H$ might also satisfy some additional relations not satisfied in $G$?

Comment: Well, I didn't really think about it. It might be. But we still have two groups that are generated by the same set. How can they not be equal? can you please give an example?

Comment: Consider $G=\langle x|\rangle$ and $H=\langle x|x\rangle$. Then $G\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $H\cong\{1\}$.